# How to populate UIlist with certain collections?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties, collections

I'm trying to understand how to populate an `UIList` with certain collections based on their name. I am trying to extend [this very useful answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146563/how-to-compile-template-list-with-some-object-in-scene-2-8.) by @batFINGER In addition, I would like to be able to show a button/operator alongside each collection shown in the same row, if that's possible. Based on this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167878/how-to-get-all-collections-of-the-current-scene) collections can be iterated and returned using a `BoolProperty`:

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

coll = bpy.context.scene.collection

for c in traverse_tree(coll):
    if c.col_prop.tag:
        print(c.name)

class CollectionPropertyArchive(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    tag: BoolProperty(default=False)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CollectionPropertyArchive)            
    bpy.types.Collection.col_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
            type = CollectionPropertyArchive)

def unregister():

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CollectionPropertyArchive)
```

**Q:** How to populate an `UIlist` with certain collections?

Comment: @brockmann My mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate that you're trying to keep things organized @RayMairlot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go get the *UIList* for materials for 2.8x from [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box/30446#30446)

Set the type of the `PointerProperty` to `bpy.types.Collection` in order to store a pointer to the collection per item added to the `PropertyGroup`. No matter if the user adds new objects, changes the name of the collection or anything else, it always returns the reference added to the list:

```
class CUSTOM_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    #name: StringProperty() -> Instantiated by default
    coll_ptr: PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection)
```

Edit the `draw_item` method to display the items properly (you can use a label too):

```
def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
    split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
    split.label(text="Index: %d" % (index))
    split.prop(item.coll_ptr, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon="COLLECTION_NEW")
```

The last tiny bit you have to implement is a new operator to append the collections to your UIList. To get the idea I modified `CUSTOM_OT_actions`operator to add the *active* collection to the list. Just add a new item and assign the *collection object* to the `coll_ptr` variable declared before:

```
if self.action == 'ADD':
    act_coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
    if act_coll.name in [c[1].name for c in scn.custom.items()]:
        info = '"%s" already in the list' % (act_coll.name)
    else:
        item = scn.custom.add()
        item.coll_ptr = act_coll
        item.name = item.coll_ptr.name
        scn.custom_index = (len(scn.custom)-1)
        info = '%s added to list' % (item.name)

    self.report({'INFO'}, info)
```

[image]

Once a few items have been added to the list, you can use the console to make sure all is working. You can easily print the names of the collections, the objects per collection or whatever...

```
>>> for coll in C.scene.custom:
...     print (coll.coll_ptr.name)
...     
Collection
Collection 2


>>> for coll in C.scene.custom:
...     for ob in coll.coll_ptr.objects:
...         print (ob)
...         
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Light")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Camera")>
```

---

To set the selected collection of the list as active collection in the *Outliner*, you can use a callback for `custom_index` property see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example

[image]

Note: You don't need that extra `bool`, just add the collection to the list when adding a new one to the scene.

Comment: Thanks to you now, I understood something more and I was also able to build a callback function that activates the collection in the outsider which is updated through IntProperty to which the UIList index refers

Comment: I have managed as well, but if I change one of the collection's name in the UI, that renamed collection is not activated.

Comment: Sorry to bring up this thread again and sorry for the possible beginner's question: How can I reuse the same operator class with different UI_Lists? How do I pass the different coll_ptr and coll_ptr.index to the same operator when I call it from two different UI_Lists in the UI? Currently I created 2 operator classes in which only the ptr and ptr_index are different. Not very efficient...