# UIlist selection issues when clicking on icon but not in dropdown

Tags: python

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import os
import collections
import json
import random
import copy
from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       Panel,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       IntProperty,
                       CollectionProperty,
                       UIList)

def select_current_selset(self, context):
    """Selection"""
    if len(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items) is 0:
        return None

    index = int(self.selection_set_dplist)
    obj_list = json.loads(
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_items[index].object_list,
        object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
    
    if len(obj_list) is 0:
        return None

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for obj in obj_list:
        if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj):
            bpy.data.objects[obj].select_set(True)

    if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_list[0]):
        context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_list[0]]
    return None


def get_selection_list_items(scene, context):
    """Get a list of selection sets"""
    items = []
    for i, item in enumerate(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items, 0):
        items.append((str(i), item.set_name, ''))

    if len(items) is 0:
        items.append(('0', 'Selection Set Empty.', ''))

    return items


def get_sel_set_item_name(self):
    return self["set_name"]


def set_sel_set_item_name(self, value):
    self["set_name"] = value
    current_names = [i.set_name for i in bpy.context.scene.sj_sel_set_items]
    current_names.remove(value)
    new_name = value
    cnt = 1
    while new_name in current_names:
        new_name = '{}.{:03d}'.format(new_name.split('.')[0], cnt)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    self["set_name"] = new_name
    return None


class SJSelectionSetItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """Selection set collection item"""

    set_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="SelectionSet",
        name="Selection set name",
        get=get_sel_set_item_name,
        set=set_sel_set_item_name
        )
    object_list: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Objects in set",
        description="",
        default="")
        
class SJSelectionSetProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """Define custom properties"""
    bl_label = ""
    
    selection_set_dplist: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=get_selection_list_items,
        name="Selection Set",
        description="Select objects from the Selected Set",
        update=select_current_selset
    )


class SJSelectionSetAddItem(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add new selection set"""
    bl_idname = "sj_selection_set.add_selset"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = "Add new Selection Set from selected objects"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        """"""
        if len(bpy.context.selected_objects) is 0:
            msg = 'Please Select any object.'
            def draw(self, context):
                self.layout.label(text=msg)
            bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title="Info", icon="INFO")
            self.report({'INFO'}, msg)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        new_item = context.scene.sj_sel_set_items.add()

        current_names = [i.set_name for i in context.scene.sj_sel_set_items]
        new_name = 'SelectionSet'
        cnt = 1
        while new_name in current_names:
            new_name = 'SelectionSet.{:03d}'.format(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        new_item.set_name = new_name

        index = len(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items) - 1
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_item_index = index
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_props.selection_set_dplist = str(index)

        obj_list = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
        new_item.object_list = json.dumps(obj_list)

        get_selection_list_items(self, context)
        bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SJSelectionSetSelect(bpy.types.Operator):
    r"""Select objects in selected set"""
    bl_idname = "sj_selection_set.select"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = "Select objects in selected set"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.sj_sel_set_items

    def execute(self, context):
        r""""""
        index = context.scene.sj_sel_set_item_index
        obj_list = json.loads(
            context.scene.sj_sel_set_items[index].object_list,
            object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)

        if len(obj_list) is 0:
            return {'FINISHED'}
    
        
        for obj in obj_list:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj):
                bpy.data.objects[obj].select_set(True)

        if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_list[0]):
            context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_list[0]]
        return {'FINISHED'}


########### UI ##########
        
class SJSelectionSetEditList(bpy.types.UIList):
    r""""""
    def draw_item(
        self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        custom_icon = 'OBJECT_HIDDEN'

        layout.prop(item, "set_name", text="", emboss=False, icon=custom_icon)
        layout.operator("sj_selection_set.select", icon="RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF")


 
class SJSelectionSetListPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """UI"""
    bl_label = "Selection Set List"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_category = "SJT"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'} 

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sjss = context.scene.sj_sel_set_props
        ob = context.object    

        row = layout.row()
        sub_row = row.row(align=True)
        sub_row.operator("sj_selection_set.add_selset", text="New Selection Set")
        layout.separator(factor=0.5)

        row = layout.row()
        sub_row = row.row()
        sub_row.prop(sjss, "selection_set_dplist", text="Selection Set")

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("SJSelectionSetEditList", "Sel Set List", context.scene, "sj_sel_set_items", context.scene, "sj_sel_set_item_index", rows=1)


classes = (
    SJSelectionSetItem,
    SJSelectionSetProperties,
    SJSelectionSetAddItem,
    SJSelectionSetSelect,
    SJSelectionSetEditList,
    SJSelectionSetListPanel,
    )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SJSelectionSetProperties)
    bpy.types.Scene.testprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(select_current_selset)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_items = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SJSelectionSetItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_item_index = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Objects in set", default=0)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_props
    del bpy.types.Object.action_list_index



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I have couple of issues with the selection in the list using blender 2.93.5, will try to explain...
I'm using the code from a free addon created long time ago from another person.
The dropdown menu works as expected by selecting all the objects from the selection set, now what I'm after is to get rid of the dropdown menu and use the icons in the ui to perform the same task than the dropdown menu.

[image]

- The first issue I have is that to make the button on the UIlist to select the objects that belong to that selection set, I need first to select the row and then click on the icon.
- The second issue I have is that the icon selection works different than the dropdown menu when having multiple objects inside the selection set.
  Here a short gif showing both issues:

[image]

I have been spending few days already reading the manuals about the callback https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example
and this: [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box) and this:[How to populate UIlist with certain collections?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/how-to-populate-uilist-with-certain-collections), but no matter what I try I cannot make it work under this script, not sure if is because my limited knowledge or something else.

Comment: You're globally deselecting at every iteration of your for loop so logically at the end you only have 1 selected object. 
            `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')`

Comment: Thank you, was so easy at the end. Now one of the issues is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close...

1. As for getting the operator icon/button to get the right set without selecting the row, I added an index prop to the `SJSelectionSetSelect`. This keeps it self-contained in the operator; you could even remove the global index property.

```py
class SJSelectionSetSelect(bpy.types.Operator):
    #...

    index: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Objects in set", default=0)

    # in execute()
        obj_list = json.loads(
            context.scene.sj_sel_set_items[self.index].object_list,
            object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

And then you can set the index in the panel:

```py
class SJSelectionSetEditList(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, blah_blah_blah, index):
        # ...
        op = layout.operator("sj_selection_set.select", icon="RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF")
        op.index = index
```

2. As @Gorgious said, you needed to move your `select_all(action='DESELECT')` out of your loop so it doesn't repeatedly clear as you're selecting.

tl:dr, here is the final code (I removed some unused pieces for brevity):

```py
import bpy
import collections
import json


def select_current_selset(self, context):
    """Selection"""
    if len(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items) is 0:
        return None

    index = int(self.selection_set_dplist)
    obj_list = json.loads(
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_items[index].object_list,
        object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)

    if len(obj_list) is 0:
        return None

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for obj in obj_list:
        if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj):
            bpy.data.objects[obj].select_set(True)

    if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_list[0]):
        context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_list[0]]
    return None


def get_selection_list_items(scene, context):
    """Get a list of selection sets"""
    items = []
    for i, item in enumerate(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items, 0):
        items.append((str(i), item.set_name, ''))

    if len(items) is 0:
        items.append(('0', 'Selection Set Empty.', ''))

    return items


def get_sel_set_item_name(self):
    return self["set_name"]


def set_sel_set_item_name(self, value):
    self["set_name"] = value
    current_names = [i.set_name for i in bpy.context.scene.sj_sel_set_items]
    current_names.remove(value)
    new_name = value
    cnt = 1
    while new_name in current_names:
        new_name = '{}.{:03d}'.format(new_name.split('.')[0], cnt)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    self["set_name"] = new_name
    return None


class SJSelectionSetItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """Selection set collection item"""

    set_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="SelectionSet",
        name="Selection set name",
        get=get_sel_set_item_name,
        set=set_sel_set_item_name
    )
    object_list: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Objects in set",
        description="",
        default="")


class SJSelectionSetProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """Define custom properties"""
    bl_label = ""

    selection_set_dplist: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=get_selection_list_items,
        name="Selection Set",
        description="Select objects from the Selected Set",
        update=select_current_selset
    )


class SJSelectionSetAddItem(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add new selection set"""
    bl_idname = "sj_selection_set.add_selset"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = "Add new Selection Set from selected objects"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        """"""
        if len(bpy.context.selected_objects) is 0:
            msg = 'Please Select any object.'

            def draw(self, context):
                self.layout.label(text=msg)

            bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title="Info", icon="INFO")
            self.report({'INFO'}, msg)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        new_item = context.scene.sj_sel_set_items.add()

        current_names = [i.set_name for i in context.scene.sj_sel_set_items]
        new_name = 'SelectionSet'
        cnt = 1
        while new_name in current_names:
            new_name = 'SelectionSet.{:03d}'.format(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        new_item.set_name = new_name

        index = len(context.scene.sj_sel_set_items) - 1
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_item_index = index
        context.scene.sj_sel_set_props.selection_set_dplist = str(index)

        obj_list = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
        new_item.object_list = json.dumps(obj_list)

        get_selection_list_items(self, context)
        bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class SJSelectionSetSelect(bpy.types.Operator):
    r"""Select objects in selected set"""
    bl_idname = "sj_selection_set.select"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = "Select objects in selected set"

    index: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Objects in set", default=0)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.sj_sel_set_items

    def execute(self, context):
        r""""""
        obj_list = json.loads(
            context.scene.sj_sel_set_items[self.index].object_list,
            object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)

        if len(obj_list) is 0:
            return {'FINISHED'}

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        for obj in obj_list:
            if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj):
                bpy.data.objects[obj].select_set(True)

        if context.scene.objects.get(obj_list[0]):
            context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj_list[0]]
        return {'FINISHED'}


########### UI ##########

class SJSelectionSetEditList(bpy.types.UIList):
    r""""""

    def draw_item(
            self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        custom_icon = 'OBJECT_HIDDEN'

        layout.prop(item, "set_name", text="", emboss=False, icon=custom_icon)
        op = layout.operator("sj_selection_set.select", icon="RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF")
        op.index = index


class SJSelectionSetListPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """UI"""
    bl_label = "Selection Set List"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_category = "SJT"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        sub_row = row.row(align=True)
        sub_row.operator("sj_selection_set.add_selset", text="New Selection Set")
        layout.separator(factor=0.5)

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("SJSelectionSetEditList", "Sel Set List", context.scene, "sj_sel_set_items", context.scene,
                          "sj_sel_set_item_index", rows=1)


classes = (
    SJSelectionSetItem,
    SJSelectionSetProperties,
    SJSelectionSetAddItem,
    SJSelectionSetSelect,
    SJSelectionSetEditList,
    SJSelectionSetListPanel,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SJSelectionSetProperties)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_items = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SJSelectionSetItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_item_index = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Objects in set", default=0)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.sj_sel_set_props
    del bpy.types.Object.action_list_index


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Cheers :)