# Selecting collections in UIlist not working when collection's name changes

Tags: python

I have a script (from [Populate UIlist with Certain Collections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/how-to-populate-uilist-with-certain-collections)) that creates new collections into the scene and populate the UIlist with them which can be selected via the ui. Everything is working properly until I rename one of the already created collection, then that new renamed collection cannot be selected anymore.

After I rename a collection and try to selecte it via ui I get this message in the console:

*File "\Text", line 34, in update_func
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: ViewLayer.active_layer_collection does not support a 'None' assignment LayerCollection type
File "\Text", line 18, in update_func*

Here is the script:

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       CollectionProperty,
                       PointerProperty)

from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       Panel,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       UIList)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Functions
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

def update_func(self, context):
    scn = context.scene
    idx = scn.custom_index
    item = scn.custom[idx]

    def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
        found = None
        if (layerColl.name == collName):
            return layerColl
        for layer in layerColl.children:
            found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
            if found:
                return found
    
    layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
    layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, item.name)
    bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operators
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_OT_actions(Operator):
    """Move items up and down, add and remove"""
    bl_idname = "custom.list_action"
    bl_label = "List Actions"
    bl_description = "Move items up and down, add and remove"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    action: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""),
            ('ADD', "Add", "")))

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.custom_index


        def find_layer_collection_recursive(find, col):
            for c in col.children:
                if c.collection == find:
                    return c
            return None


        # List of object references
        objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

        # create the collection
        my_collection = bpy.data.collections.new("MY CUSTOM NAME")
        # link it to the scene
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(my_collection)

        # now find the matching layer collection for the collection you created
        found = find_layer_collection_recursive(my_collection, bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection)
        if found:
            # once it's found, set the active layer collection to the one we found
            bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = found


        # Loop through all objects
        for ob in objs:
            my_collection.objects.link(ob)
         
        act_coll = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
        item = scn.custom.add()
        item.coll_ptr = act_coll
        item.name = item.coll_ptr.name
        scn.custom_index = (len(scn.custom)-1)
        info = '%s added to list' % (item.name)
        self.report({'INFO'}, info)
        return {"FINISHED"}

class CUSTOM_OT_clearList(Operator):
    """Clear all items of the list"""
    bl_idname = "custom.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items of the list"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.custom)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)

    def execute(self, context):
        if bool(context.scene.custom):
            context.scene.custom.clear()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")
        return{'FINISHED'}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Drawing
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        split = layout.split(factor=0.3)
        split.label(text="Index: %d" % (index))
        split.prop(item.coll_ptr, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon="COLLECTION_NEW")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass   

class CUSTOM_PT_objectList(Panel):
    """Adds a custom panel to the TEXT_EDITOR"""
    bl_idname = 'TEXT_PT_my_panel'
    bl_space_type = "TEXT_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Custom Object List Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = bpy.context.scene

        rows = 2
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("CUSTOM_UL_items", "", scn, "custom", scn, "custom_index", rows=rows)

        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.operator("custom.list_action", icon='ZOOM_IN', text="").action = 'ADD'

        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("custom.clear_list", icon="X")


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Collection
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class CUSTOM_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    coll_ptr: PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection,
        update=update_func
    )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Register & Unregister
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    CUSTOM_OT_actions,
    CUSTOM_OT_clearList,
    CUSTOM_UL_items,
    CUSTOM_PT_objectList,
    CUSTOM_objectCollection,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    # Custom scene properties
    bpy.types.Scene.custom = CollectionProperty(type=CUSTOM_objectCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.custom_index = IntProperty(update=update_func)


def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.custom
    del bpy.types.Scene.custom_index


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the update function from `coll_ptr`.

```
class CUSTOM_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    coll_ptr: PointerProperty(
        name="Collection",
        type=bpy.types.Collection
    )
```

> To set the selected collection of the list as active collection in the Outliner, you can use a callback for **custom_index** property

**EDIT** ... and use `coll_ptr.name` in your update callback to get the name of the collection.

```
def update_func(self, context):
    idx = context.scene.custom_index
    item = context.scene.custom[idx]
    
    def find_layer_collection(layer_coll, coll_name):
        c = None
        if (layer_coll.name == coll_name):
            return layer_coll
        for layer in layer_coll.children:
            c = find_layer_collection(layer, coll_name)
            if c:
                return c
    
    vl = context.view_layer
    vl.active_layer_collection = find_layer_collection(vl.layer_collection, item.coll_ptr.name)
```