# How to create a UIList that shows all cameras in the scene?

Tags: scripting, interface, camera

I'm currently trying to create a small addon that helps me with rendering different camera views. I'm a complete beginner and struggle with creating a UIList.

How can I achieve something like this but with cameras (the checkbox also needs to be there)?

[image]

Comment: i think this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/how-to-populate-uilist-with-certain-collections can help u a bit