# list of scene UI

Tags: python, scene, panel

I want to make list of scenes, and found blender list ui using template_list from [How to compile template_list with some object in scene 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146563/how-to-compile-template-list-with-some-object-in-scene-2-8).

I think it would be possible writing like..

```
col.template_list("CUSTOM_UL_List","",bpy.data,"scenes",bpy.data,"...")
```

I don't know how to use "active_..._index" from that UIList panel.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make a list of all the scenes in your .blend file (assuming that is what you actually meant in your question, which is a little vague)

```
scenes = []
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scenes.append(scene)
```

Comment: well, I want to make UI displaying scenes in my .blend file, not just python console :(