# How can I access scene materials and material_slots in Blender 2,92

Tags: python, materials, scene

I have a script, which works in version 2.90, in which I get a list of materials in the scene by accessing bpy.context.scene.material_slots and bpy.context.scene.materials.  These don't seem to work in version 2.92.  Did the location of the materials in the scene change and if so, how do I find them?

Comment: AFAIK `scene.material_slots` and `scene.material` have never existed by default. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141179/how-to-populate-uilist-with-all-material-slot-in-scene-2-8/141207

Comment: Thanks.  I think I had based my code on that answer.  Perhaps I did not apply it correctly and that is why my code worked in version 2.90 but not 2.92.  I tried the example in that answer, and it does not seem to generate an error message in 2.92, but after a few minutes, Blender crashes.  It happens consistently when I use it on an older (~7 years old) Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: I probably tried out the code you mentioned and then saved a startup.blend file with the custom properties, so when I changed startup.blend files, the properties disappeared.  I have been trying to learn more about custom properties.

Comment: If you append an addon `bl_info` (see `Text Editor > Templates > Python > Addon`) at the top of script, could install it as an addon (+add innards to  the  `unregister()` method)`