# Custom search data to UILayout.prop_search

Tags: scripting, materials, add-on

I need to create a searchable material dropdown that excludes grease pencil materials. However if I do it like this

```
row.prop_search(item, "material_selector", bpy.data, "materials")
```

then all the materials in scene get included in material dropdown.
How can I give custom search elements to `prop_search` method instead of generic `bpy.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a pointer property with a poll.**

To distinguish a regular material from one for a gp object there is the handy attribute `Material.is_grease_pencil`

Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159155/15543 and using a poll method https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101303/15543

Will narrow down the selection based and offer the same choices as the regular material drop down.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty

def poll_material(self, material):
    return not material.is_grease_pencil

class TEST_PT_layout_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Prop Panels"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop_search(scene, "prop", bpy.data, "materials")
        #or 
        col.prop(scene, "prop")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.prop = PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.Material,
        poll=poll_material,
        )
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_layout_panel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.prop
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Kinda related:

[How to populate UIList with all material slot in scene? 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141179/how-to-populate-uilist-with-all-material-slot-in-scene-2-8)

Comment: Never got notified about your comment here (coming from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203312/31447) after reading your answer. I feel honored, thanks! However, I guess I'm too grumpy for that and don't like the lazy peps just asking something... I honestly was in hope you would participate. Regarding python questions as well as flagging dupes the reality is that nothing really changed after the election -> your vote, duartes vote, my vote, which is a bit disappointing IMO. We will see, hopefully that will change. Cheers